# HXT skip element on error

Tags: haskell, hxt

I am iterating over list of tables and inside a `proc` I am using function which may throw an exception (I can't change its behaviour):

```
parseThing :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree Thing
parseThing = deep (hasName "table") &&& deep (hasName "h3") >>> proc (table, h3) -> do
  name <- getText <<< getChildren -< h3
  info -< listA parseTable -< table

  returnA $ mkThing name info -- may throw an exception
```

where `parseTable :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree (String, String)` parses `<tr><td>key</td><td>value</td></tr>` into a `(key, value)` tuple and `mkThing :: String -> [(String, String)] -> Thing` builds Thing by `name` and `info` and may throw an exception (it depends on both name and info)

How can I skip processing the thing which cannot be build? If I leave exception uncaught it converts to string somehow and walks into output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`catchA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowExc.html) arrow to handle exceptions inside the pipeline. In that case `parseThing` needs to be of more specific IO-aware type like [`IOSArrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState-TypeDefs.html#t%3aIOSArrow).

To skip exceptions, [`catchA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowExc.html)
is given [`none`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v%3anone) arrow as an exception handler.

Here is a full example (I extracted `parseThing_aux` from `parseThing` for better readability):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import Control.Arrow.ArrowExc (catchA)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core


data Thing = Thing String [(String,String)] deriving Show


main :: IO ()
main = do
  xml <- getContents
  res <- runX $ readString [] xml >>> parseThing
  mapM_ print res


parseThing :: IOSArrow XmlTree Thing
parseThing
  = deep (hasName "table") &&& deep (hasName "h3")
  >>> catchA parseThing_aux none


parseThing_aux :: IOSArrow (XmlTree, XmlTree) Thing
parseThing_aux = proc (table, h3) -> do
    name <- getText <<< getChildren -< h3
    info <- listA parseTable -< table
    returnA -< mkThing name info


parseTable :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree (String, String)
parseTable = error "Not implemented"


mkThing :: String -> [(String,String)] -> Thing
mkThing n i = Thing n i
```

### Side note 1

In case you would like to zip tables and headers instead of making cross product of them, you can change `parseThing` to

```
parseThing
  = (listA $ deep $ hasName "table") &&& (listA $ deep $ hasName "h3")
  >>> arr2 zip >>> unlistA
  >>> catchA parseThing_aux none
```

### Side note 2

It is a little bit more concise to write `parseThing_aux` in point-free style

```
parseThing_aux
  = (getChildren >>> getText) *** listA parseTable
  >>^ uncurry mkThing
```

(You can eliminate `uncurry` by changing `mkThing` to take a pair.)